# How to check whether a column in a table is strictly monotonically increasing?

Tags: sql, dolphindb, inorder

I want to check whether a column in a table is strictly monotonically increasing. How can I do this? Is the expression `a>=prev(a)` valid in DolphinDB? Does anyone know a built-in function for this purpose? If so, can you share some best practices? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `isSorted`, for example:

```
t = table(`a`b`c`a`d`e as sym, 1 3 3 5 6 7 as id)
select isSorted(id) from t // true

t = table(`a`b`c`a`d`e as sym, 4 3 3 5 6 7 as id)
select isSorted(id) from t // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You expression is OK. To get the final result:

```
all(a >= prev(a))
```

Be careful if any `NULL` in `a`.